# Why Powerpoint VSTO Add-in TextRange.Find(str) returns null?

Tags: c#, textbox, vsto, powerpoint, add-in

I am trying to format the written text with the add-in. Button code should find the string inside the slides and change it accordingly.

In detail:

Code loops over slides and shapes in each slide. When it finds a textbox or another shape containing string "CO2" it should add it to a list. Then it will correct it.

In a particular slide, there is one textbox containing "CO2" string only, TextRange.Find("CO2") returns null which raises an exception.

```
string co2 = "CO2"
if (shp.HasTextFrame == OfC.MsoTriState.msoTrue && shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text.Contains(co2))
{
   int index = textRange.Text.IndexOf(co2);
   while (index != -1)
   {
      var textRangeCO2 = textRange.Find(co2, index);
   }
}
```

where in this code textRangeCO2 becomes null there are other textboxes that does not have any problem.

What could be the problem with that particular textbox. When I copy the next textbox to the same place and change the string inside it to "CO2" code works without any issue.

Comment: It's a bit surprising. Are you sure the text really is "CO2" ? 
may it's 0 and not O, or it could be there is an invisible character somewhere in the string ?

Comment: As you see it gets index without any problems which ensure that it is not "0" but "O". Even it contains additional characters, it must filter out the CO2 part. Anyway, I just figured out that, the text box is inserted from a diagram creator software called "think cell". If you copy and paste as plain text in the same text box it works with no problem. I am just informing the user saying that there are co2 which will not be corrected automatically.